# I accidentally ran "apt install gnome", how can I revert it without uninstalling stuff that I need?

Tags: apt, 22.04

I wanted to install a package that started with gnome- and accidentally ran `apt install gnome`. As soon as I realized my mistake I canceled the installation using ctrl+z.
How can I check if anything has been installed/changed and revert this without breaking the system? 
I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: There is a log entry in history that lists a number of packages, and the term.log is the output of apt. I cancelled it at the stage where it said "Selecting previously unselected package XYZ" "Unpacking XYZ". Are all those "previously unselected packages" safe to remove? I am afraid to remove packages that I had previously, just not manually installed

Comment: Keep reading: Apt logs as it works; it does not summarize. Your question might be answered on the next line or two. You will figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apt logs deb packages installs and removals.

See the following logfiles to discover what package changes (if any) were made:

```
/var/log/apt/history.log
/var/log/apt/term.log
```

If you discover that packages were installed that you don't want, simply use apt to remove them.

```
sudo apt remove package1 package2 package3 package4 packageN
```

Comment: How can I make sure that none of these were installed before I ran this command? I am afraid that I may have had some packages before (but maybe marked as a dependency and not manually installed) and that I will break my system by removing them. I am already getting error messages on boot (contacts not working, clocks not working) although so far I have done nothing except for cancelling the installation.

Comment: "*I am afraid that...I will break my system by removing them*" Then read your apt output before agreeing to any removals. If the output includes important applications or is very lengthy, then simply tell apt "No". Advice: ALWAYS read your apt output before agreeing -- doing so will save you much grief.

Comment: That is what I should have done in the first place. Obviously I will now read carefully what I remove, but how do I know what's part of gnome(-core) and what belongs to Ubuntu-Desktop (which is also gnome)?

Comment: @Gasp0de If a package had been installed before you ran `apt install gnome` it was not installed again and therefor does not appear in the logs from that command.

Comment: "*how do I know what's part of gnome(-core) and what belongs to Ubuntu-Desktop*" Apt will tell you in the output. It won't say so in those terms, but you will understand that if apt offers to remove `ubuntu-desktop` now you know and can refuse the offer.